PowerApps CoE Kit
I have downloaded the Centre of Excellence kit but I couldn't find themeing component in it, is it removed from CoE kit or there is some specific steps needs to follow in order to get it in the solution?
I needed it to create custom theme.
I downloaded the latest version of CoE starter kit and then I checked all the components but themeing component was not there in order to create the custom theme I was expecting the themeing app. the themeing component missing in the zip file.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

the themeing component is missed in the CoE starter Kit, is there a way we can get it?
